# In SBA UI I cannot find the WEB menu or HttpTrace menu how to enable it

Tags: spring-boot-admin, http-trace

I have created a spring boot 3 admin server and connected applications as clients but in the UI I cannot find the WEB menu or HttpTrace menu how to enable it

I have given "*" in endpoint enable property so all menus should be available but Web or Http trace missing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `HttpTraces` endpoint has been renamed to `HttpExchanges` as stated here in the migration guide: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#httptrace-endpoint-renamed-to-httpexchanges

In order to activate the `HttpExchanges` endpoint, you have to declare a Bean as follows, too:

```
@Bean
public HttpExchangeRepository httpTraceRepository() {
    return new InMemoryHttpExchangeRepository();
}
```